# Is this question about data storage on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

There has been some discussion about the following question:

[is data received after transmission immediately stored?and can that be recovered](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/79624/755)

Is it on-topic?  It appears there are some mixed points of view.  On the one hand, computer networks and communications are within the scope of CS.  On the other hand, if the question is about specific implementations rather than fundamental principles or concepts, is it on-topic?

(Taking this to meta, since it seems like comment threads might not be the best way to come to a resolution.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe this post looks dumb since I'm writing it after the question already has an accepted answer but...

I think the question is unanswerable. Although it mentions TCP, which has well-defined behaviour, everything in the question is completely up to the application that's using TCP. As such, I don't think the question is really well-formed, so "on-topic?" isn't really the issue.